# CoreData - Unique Values from subEntity....?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest

iPhone CoreData funky fetch-request:
I want to build function to retrieve array of Unique-CategoryCodes for my products
I have Entity "Product" and there is a field(Property) Category. 
Of course Category is the Relationship to the Categories Entity.

This if my function:

```
- (NSArray *)uniqueCategoriesWithQuery:(NSString *)query {
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];    
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"Code"]]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:YES];
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *result = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
DebugLog(@"%@", result);
if (fetchError == nil && [result count] > 0) {
    return result;
}
return nil;
```

}

MyResult:
2010-12-10 05:55:33.683 iApp[3453:307] -[ShoppingHelper uniqueCategoriesWithQuery:] [Line 1193] (
        {
        Category = "0x495a200 ";
    },
        {
        Category = "0x4959ce0 ";
    }
)

Code works well but I can not use results at all. I have got my categories ... but ID' instead of NSStrings.. How to consume it?

maybe I should be using:
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"Categories.Code"]]];

to get the NSStrings in the Distinct NSDictionary?

OR

find Category BY ID  - How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you avoid using `NSDictionaryResultType`, and instead let it return managed objects, you can just access the `Category` objects through the appropriate property on the returned `Product` objects. From there, you can get whatever information you need from each category. Although, if you do this, and have a very large result set, you may want to [set the fetch batch size](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW28).

Comment: Thanks, but If I return managed objects the "setReturnsDistinctResults:YES" does not work - I get all the products. I just need unique categories for filtered products table. Something like SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Products WHERE ProductName like '%mylikeString%'.